# Why my .htaccess in codeigniter is different

Tags: codeigniter

All of my `.htaccess` in `codeigniter` like this

```
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
```

But all tutorial `.htaccess` are like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need help to remove `index.php` url in `codeigniter`.
Why should I replace all code `.htaccess` like tutorial said ?

Comment: You can check what every of those rule does on [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) official page. Check some commonly used mods/rules [here](https://github.com/Tpojka/htaccess). Edit: This was answer to question which doesn't fit the issue well. Usually I am using [this](https://github.com/Tpojka/general-ci-htaccess/blob/master/.htaccess) file.

Comment: The tutorial stuff is okay. Based on the server configuration you may need to permit rewrite mod enable for that folder.

Comment: The first htaccess looks like it's one from application folder if you need to remove the index.php from url it goes in the main directory out side of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should you replace all code .htaccess like tutorial said ?**

Yes! just in the root directory of your CodeIgniter project.

**Why?**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The CodeIgniter documentation says that by the rules given in .htaccess file, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.

without these rules, for example, you'll have to access your login page like this

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php/<controllerName>/login
```

with the rules in .htaccess file it's

```
http://yourdomain.com/<controllerName>/login
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, now i know about .htaccess more then before. And now i can accsess my application in codeigniter without index.php